# HTML Aislado | Vue Js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Estoy intentando una forma de poner HTML Aislado dentro de mi código para hacer una especie de Sandbox HTML, donde con un Textarea se ingrese código HTML y se previsualice, pero que este HTML que está siendo previsualizado (utilizando vue, o sea el v-html) no pueda afectar la demás parte del código, que si insertan algún script y/o estilos, no afecte la demás partes de la página.

Lo intente con un `<iframe/>` pero el mismo solo recibe un url y yo quiero pasarlo dinámicamente ya sea como un hijo o como prop

```
 <div v-html="description"></div>
```

Esto funciona, pero no esta aislado del resto de código.

```
 <iframe v-html="description" />
```

Esto no funciona.

Comment: ¿Con aislado quieres decir fuera del div con id="app"?

Comment: No, con aislado me refiero a lo mismo que hace un iframe. Por ejemplo, si añado el cdn de bootstrap, se aplicara a toda la pagina, lo mismo pasaria si fuera un script, y eso no seria tan seguro.